# Erro ao inserir dados no LokiJS com VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nosql, electron

Olá, estou iniciando em Electron com VueJS1.0 && LokiJS e tenho tido dificuldade em encontrar a solução para o erro que acontece sempre que vou inserir um segundo dado a Collection:

Erro:

> Uncaught Error: Document is already in collection, please use update()

cadastro-cliente.html

```
<form class="pane-body" id="formCadastrarCliente">
        <h3>Cadastro de Cliente</h3>
        <div class="form-group form-nome">
          <input type="text" id="nome" class="form-control" v-model="cliente.nome" placeholder="Nome" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-dataNasc">
          <input type="date" id="dataNasc" class="form-control" v-model="cliente.dataNasc" placeholder="DataNasc">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-cpf">
          <input type="text" id="cpf" class="form-control" v-model="cliente.cpf" placeholder="CPF">
        </div>

        <a href="index.html"><button type="button" id="cancelar" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button></a>
        <button type="button" @click="salvarCliente()" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

cadastro-cliente.js

```
var read = require('read-file-utf8')
var loki = require('lokijs');// instanciando o Banco de dados
var db = new loki('db.json');//Criando o banco de dados 
var data = read(__dirname + '/db.json');
db.loadJSON(data);

var clientes = db.getCollection('clientes');
if (!clientes)
{
    clientes = db.addCollection('clientes');
    db.save();
}

function ready(fn) {
    if (document.readyState != 'loading')
    {
      fn();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
    }
}


window.Vue = require('vue');
new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
        cliente: {/*objeto Cliente com valores default*/
            nome: '',
            dataNasc: '',
            cpf: ''
         }

    },
    methods:
    {
        salvarCliente: function ()
        {
            if (this.cliente.nome != '')
            {
                clientes.insert(this.cliente);
                db.save();
                document.getElementById("formCadastrarCliente").reset();
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Eu insiro os dados no form, salvo-os, limpo o form e quando insiro novos dados e mando salvar acusa o erro:

> Uncaught Error: Document is already in collection, please use update()

Se alguém souber qual meu erro, desde já, agradeço!

Comment: `VueJS1.0`? Tens a certeza que queres usar a versão 1?

Comment: Como estou aprendendo agora, resolvi seguir um tutorial no qual usavam a versão 1.0. Mas se versão 2.0 resolver esse problema, eu posso migrar pra ela kkk

Comment: Usa, sem dúvida, o Vue 2. A versão 3 está quase a sair. Testa com Vue 2 e se não conseguires diz-me.

Comment: Ainda não mudei para o VueJS2.0, mas descobri o erro. Quando eu inseria o primeiro objeto na collection Cliente o Loki JS adicionava mais um atributo ao objeto de com valores default: o $loki, que é a chave primária. E devido ao data-binding o $loki era mantido para as inserções seguintes, repetindo a chave primária. Refiz o método salvarCliente: <br/>

Comment: salvarCliente: function ()
        { let cli : { nome : this.cliente.nome, cpf: this.cliente.cpf, dataNasc : this.cliente.dataNasc}
            if (cli.nome != ' ')
            {
                clientes.insert(cli);
                db.save();
                document.getElementById("formCadastrarCliente").reset();
            }
        }

Comment: Assim não pega o $loki. Obrigado!!!